# Send data from Kinesis firehose to self managed ELK setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a self-managed ELK setup on a ec2 instance. I'm trying to send data from Kinesis data firehose to my ELK setup through HTTP endpoint.
The issue is kinesis can send only PUT request and elastic search accepts only POST request.

I've created a API key in elasticsearch and provided in the Kinesis access key configuration for authorization. Using this api key i can able to do authenticate and do PUT GET POST requests on the local machine. But kinesis throwing 401 error.

How to solve the authentication and conversion of PUT into POST request between Kinesis firehose delivery and Self-managed ELK setup?